# iOS - error: Cycle inside Runner building could produce unreliable results

Tags: ios, flutter, apple-push-notifications

We have flutter project and we are trying to integrate the notification service extension to our project on iOS side. When we build the project, we get the following error:

```
error: Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle details:
→ Target 'Runner': ExtractAppIntentsMetadata
○ Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dekrseohtfpcdagiopasnlsfskgy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/NotificationService.appex' to '/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dekrseohtfpcdagiopasnlsfskgy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/PlugIns/NotificationService.appex'
○ That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “Thin Binary”
○ Target 'Runner' has process command with output '/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dekrseohtfpcdagiopasnlsfskgy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Info.plist'
○ Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dekrseohtfpcdagiopasnlsfskgy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/NotificationService.appex' to '/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dekrseohtfpcdagiopasnlsfskgy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/PlugIns/NotificationService.appex'
```

```
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbols:
```

Can anyone help us to solve this issue? Any hint or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.